# How to implement --version using python click?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, python-click

I want to implement `mycommand --version` using python click. I have something like this working but it feels kinda clunky.

```
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True, no_args_is_help=True)
@click.pass_context
@click.option('--version', 'version')
def cli(ctx, version):
    if version:
        ctx.echo(f'{sys.argv[0]} {__version__}')
        ctx.exit()
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As it turns out, `click` has a builtin decorator [`click.version_option`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.version_option) to accomplish this. The code now becomes:

```
@click.group()
@click.version_option(__version__)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks; here's a link to the docs for more info on `click.version_option` too: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=version_option#click.version_option

Comment: I added this in my click cli but it does not work on trying to run command clickcli --version

Answer (score 3):

You can use `click.version_option` decorator to implement `--version` option.

If your `setup.py` like this and have `version` click will read it automatically.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='application',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['application'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
)
```

The `click.version_option` option without any argument will read version from `setup.py`.

```
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True, no_args_is_help=True)
@click.pass_context
@click.version_option()
def cli(ctx):
   ...
```

**Run and Result**

```
$ application --version 
application, version 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to add another scenario that I ran into but isn't explicitly stated here:*

Your CLI name can be different from your entry point, which can mean you'll need to provide the name explicitly if [importlib_metadata](https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can't automatically find the name

### Error

Without `package_name='my_command_line_interface'`:

```bash
mycli --version
```

> RuntimeError: 'mycli' is not installed. Try passing 'package_name' instead.

### Setup

`setup.py`

```py
setup(
    name='my_command_line_interface',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['application'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points="""
        [console_scripts]
        mycli=my_command_line_interface.cli:cli
    """,
)
```

`cli.py`

```py
@click.group()
@click.version_option(package_name='my_command_line_interface') # <-- ADDED
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    pass
```

`__main__.py`

```py
from .cli import cli

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```